# Tengo unas dudas sobre el arreglo

Tags: array

Los arreglos son estructuras de datos compuestas que permiten manipular un conjunto de datos homogéneos, ahora bien no se si el uso del índice para el manejo del contenido de esta estructura es mejor que tener diversas variables del mismo tipo?

Y si en algún ejemplo necesito 50 datos. Entonces sería mejor el uso de  50 variables?

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta por favor, saludos!

Comment: Usar un arreglo es precisamente para no tener que usar tantas variables, te imaginas un arreglo de 1000 posiciones cambiarlo por 1000 variables, vamos que hay cosas que son obvias

Answer (score 1):

Al declarar un arreglo se reserva un espacio contiguo de memoria que puede almacenar elementos de un mismo tipo de dato.

En los lenguajes de bajo nivel se puede estudiar al arreglo de manera más detallada pues observamos que para la máquina solamente es un puntero (apuntador a un espacio de memoria) al primer elemento de memoria que se ha reservado; Esto es especialmente útil para almacenar gran cantidad datos. Sin embargo, como bien dices no se puede identificar qué dato has almacenado en cuál posición si no tienes conocimiento del orden en el que se han almacenado los datos, pues ese no es el objetivo del arreglo; para ello existen las estructuras de datos que ayudan a almacenar e identificar variables relacionadas:

Por ejemplo:

- en C existen los [structs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/structure-declarations?view=msvc-160)
- en Java los [Maps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), [HashMaps](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), etc.
- existen los [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) que son ampliamente usados.

Un ejemplo general de cómo se ven estas estructuras sería `<llave> - <valor>`

El ejemplo más sencillo de entender creo que sería con los JSON pues su estructura es muy fácil de entender y visualizar, imaginemos una estructura para describir a una persona de la siguiente manera:

```
{
   "nombre" : "Persona con apellidos",
   "edad" : 15,
   "sexo" : "masculino",
   "escolaridad" : "Secundaria",
   "alergias" : ["Chocolate", "Penicilina", "Nueces"]
}
```

De igual manera se podría hacer un arreglo de personas en el caso de que se necesite guardar a muchas personas y de cada una se necesite identificar características específicas.

```js
const people = [
  {
     "nombre" : "José Emilio Pacheco",
     "edad" : 15,
     "sexo" : "masculino",
     "escolaridad" : "Secundaria",
     "alergias" : ["Chocolate", "Penicilina", "Nueces"]
  },
  {
     "nombre" : "Jorge Muñoz Cano",
     "edad" : 11,
     "sexo" : "masculino",
     "escolaridad" : "Primaria",
     "alergias" : ["fresas"]
  },
  {
     "nombre" : "María Fernanda De La Luz",
     "edad" : 28,
     "sexo" : "femenino",
     "escolaridad" : "Maestría",
     "alergias" : ["Piña", "Manzana"]
  }
];

let str = "";
for (let person of people) {
  for (let specification in person) {
    str += `${specification} : ${person[specification]}\t`
  }
  str += "\n\n";
}

console.log(str);
```

**EDIT:**

En realidad se reservan espacios de memoria de acuerdo al dato especificado y su tamaño en bytes; por lo tanto, puedes almacenar datos de diferente tipo de dato, sin embargo, por defecto el lenguaje los va a interpretar según hayas definido tu variable.

Igual en lenguajes como Java se puede almacenar un tipo de variable general (Object) del cual extienden todos los tipos de datos (Integer, String, Float, Boolean, etc). Lo cual permite almacenar "distintos tipos de datos" (en realidad todos son dato Object). Sinceramente desconozco de otros lenguajes aunque seguramente hay más donde esto es posible.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] object = {1, "Hola", 4.5};
        System.out.println(object[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Es una buena explicacion, pero me parece que tiene detalles que no estan del todo correcto.... "puede almacenar elementos de un mismo tipo de dato." hay algun tipo de array en algun lenguaje que permita guardar elementos de tipos distintos? "En los lenguajes de bajo nivel el arreglo solamente es un puntero " te puedo asegurar que en los de alto nivel tambien, aunque nunca veas el puntero...
"para ello existen las estructuras de datos que ayudan a almacenar e identificar variables relacionadas" <- pero el array ya sabe que tipo de objetos tiene.. y el que lo programa tambien....

Comment: En tus ejemplo, yo no puedo guardar objetos (que es el ejemplo mas clasico, nadie guarda json en su programa) ??? json es un formato de intercambio de datos... dudo que guardes un array de json.. guardarias un array de objetos...

Comment: Todo depende de las necesidades del programador, en este caso sólo es para ejemplificar las estructuras de datos que probablemente es lo que esté buscando esta pregunta; en C yo uso comúnmente los structs, en especial para el manejo de memoria dinámica y sí he llegado a usar arreglos de estructuras de datos frecuentemente

Answer (score 0):

La función de los arrays es poder agrupar una lista de constantes, variables, etc en un solo 'contenedor'.

Si por ejemplo tienes 50 variables independientes como has dicho en tu ejemplo, y quieres mostrarlas por pantalla, enviarlas a otra parte de tu app, o incluso mas sencillo, si fuesen 50 variables numéricas y quisieses sumarlas entre ellas, deberías ir una por una escribiendolas y realizando la tarea en cuestión.

Si tienes un array puedes solventar este problema realizando un **for** y automatizando el proceso gracias al índice del que has preguntado.

Por ejemplo, si tienes un array numérico y quieres sumarlo con un for deberías hacer algo así:

```js
  const lista = [5,4,3,9,8];
  let sumaTotal = 0;
   
  /*Independientemente del tamaño de nuestro array, con este for podremos obtener el 
  resultado de la suma*/
  for(let i = 0; i < lista.length; i++){
    sumaTotal = sumaTotal + lista[i];
  }

  console.log('Resultado de la suma = ' + sumaTotal);
```

Comment: cual seria la diferencia entre elementos y variables? para lo unico que sirve un array es para hacer un for?